# Why Sleep() on Main function stop all threads?

Tags: c++, windows, multithreading, winapi

Why does `Sleep()` stop all created threads? I want to create a thread but keep the `Main` function in sleep until the thread finishes.

```
bool _finished = false;

void testcount(void *p){
 int i = 0;
 while(i<=30){
  i++;
  std::cout<<i<<"\n";
  Sleep(1000);
 }
_finished = true;
}
BOOL WINAPI DllMain(HINSTANCE hinstDLL, DWORD fdwReason, LPVOID lpvReserved){
 HANDLE test = NULL;
 test = CreateThread(NULL, NULL, (LPTHREAD_START_ROUTINE)testcount, NULL, NULL, NULL);
 if(test)
  std::cout<<"test thread created";
 CloseHandle(test);

 while(!_finished)
  Sleep(1000);

return true;
}
```

I am trying it now like this, but the program just never finishes, because `while` with `Sleep` stops the thread. I don't want to return anything on `Main` while thread not finished. Any solution?

Comment: before doing threads ,read the docs on DllMain

Comment: before code of new thread come to `testcount` - it will try call dlls entry points with `DLL_THREAD_ATTACH`. inside critical section (loader lock). but your first thread hold this critical section - wait here. as result - your new thread will be wait until parent thread free loader lock. but it wait until `_finished` - so for ever. deadlock

Comment: Good advice from @engf-010. Old but well written article here that should give you a good understanding. https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/?p=25283

Comment: [Dynamic-Link Library Best Practices](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/dlls/dynamic-link-library-best-practices): *"You should never perform the following tasks from within DllMain: [...] Call CreateThread. Creating a thread can work **if you do not synchronize with other threads**"*.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Calls to `DllMain` are serialised by Win32.
2. All new threads start by calling `DllMain` (with thread attach flag), and the call the method passed to `CreateThread`.

Therefore your thread is waiting to call `DllMain`, which cannot happen until your first thread leaves `DllMain`.

As commenter John Sheridan notes [Raymond Chen's blog post from 2007](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/?p=25283) is a really good explanation.

PS. for correct C/C++ library initialisation you should be using [`_beginthread` or `_beginthreadex`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/beginthread-beginthreadex?view=vs-2019) rather than `CreateThread` directly.

Comment: @han: **One** problem got fixed 17 years ago (causing a memory leak). There's still another problem present (program termination under low memory conditions), so using the CRT functions to create a thread is required, if you are using CRT functionality on that thread.

Answer (score 1):

The new thread is blocked because your main thread does not leave `DllMain`, as described in Richard's answer.

Your code also contains a data race and has undefined behavior even after this deadlock is fixed. The new thread writes to `_finished`, the main thread reads from `_finished`, concurrently. You could try to use `std::atomic<bool>` instead of `bool` to fix this, assuming availability of C++11, or you could use Win32 primitives for thread synchronization.

Changes for standard solution using `std::atomic<bool>`:

```
#include <atomic>

std::atomic<bool> finished_{false};

// Rest remains the same
```

Comment: it's not about that ,OP doesn't seem to know anything about DllMain

Comment: unrelated at all. `testcount` never begin executed.

Comment: It is not unrelated, it's not the first bug that's triggered, but it is UB. I.e. even if the init deadlock is fixed, anything is possible. In particular, the compiler could optimize away the check in the while loop.

Comment: @engf-010 - really new thread will be wait for enter loader lock with `DLL_THREAD_ATTACH`

Comment: @engf-010 - *on finish* - new thread begin infinite wait on begin execution - when try acquire loader lock. even `testcount` never begin execute. say about thread exit no sense.

Comment: @engf-010 - no, any `DLL_THREAD_DETACH` not will be here. deadlock will be exactly when new thread start - he wait on loader lock. the first thread - wait inside loader lock on `_finished`. but `_finished` never will be set to true

Comment: @engf-010 - yes - new created thread hang already on attach notify - when try enter loader lock. but he never enter - because it parent spin on `_finished` and hold loader lock. classic deadlock when both thread wait each other. of course in code many other errors, but this - exactly what now happens